# Pandas column where each value depends on another df query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I'm facing a complex problem.
I have a first dataframe in which I have customers (Note that ClientID is not Unique, you can have the same ClientID associated with a different TestDate) :

**df1 :**

```
ClientID  TestDate
1A        2019-12-24
1B        2019-08-26
1B        2020-01-12
```

I have another dataframe of "operations" indicating date and which client is involved

**df2 :**

```
LineNumber  ClientID  Date          Amount
1           1A        2020-01-12    50
2           1A        2019-09-24    15
3           1A        2019-12-25    20
4           1A        2018-12-30    30
5           1B        2018-12-30    60
6           1B        2019-12-12    40
```

What I want is to add to df1 a column containing Mean Amount and Number of Rows, but **only taking df2 rows in which Date < TestDate**

For example, for client 1A, I'll only take LineNumber 2 and 4 (because Date of line 1 and 3 is later than TestDate) and then obtain the following output for df1 :

**Expected df1 :**

```
ClientID  TestDate      NumberOp  MeanOp
1A        2019-12-24    2         22.5
1B        2019-08-26    1         60
1B        2020-01-12    2         50
```

Note : With the first row of 1B Client, since the TestDate is `2019-08-26`, only one operation is seen (the LineNumber 6 operation is done in `2019-12-12`, so AFTER testDate, so I don't take it into account).

I already have a code to do it, but I have to use `iterrows` on my `df1`, which takes ages :

**Current code (working but long) :**

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    id = row['ClientID']
    date = row['TestDate']
    df2_known = df2.loc[df2['ClientID'] == id]
    df2_known = df2_known.loc[df2_known['Date'] < date]
    df1.loc[index, 'NumberOp'] = df2_known.shape[0]
    df1.loc[index, 'MeanOp'] = df2_known['Amount'].mean()
```

I had the idea to use aggregates, and commands like `mean` and `count`, but the fact I have to filter by date for each row is a huge problem I can't figure out.
Many thanks for help in advance.

**Edit : Remaining issue :**

The fix given in the answer's edit ("in case you want to preserve missing matching keys of df2") is not corresponding to my issue.

In fact, I want to avoid losing an equivalent row of df1 if no operation in df2 can be used to calculate the mean and count.
I'll show you the problem with an example :

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['ClientID'], how='right')
print(df[df['ClientID'] == '5C'])

Output :
ClientID  TestDate    Date          Amount
5C        2019-12-12  2020-01-12    50
```

If I do the `groupby` and `transform` as it is given in the answer, my output will not have any row with `CliendID == '5C'`, because `Date < TestDate` and `Date is null` never happen, so the line is lost when I do `df = df[(df['Date']<df['TestDate']) | (df['Date'].isnull())]`. I personally want to have a row with `CliendID == '5C'` in my final output, that would look like that :

```
ClientID  TestDate      NumberOp  MeanOp
5C        2019-12-12    0         NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge and transform:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['ClientID'])
#filter based on condition
df = df[df['Date']<df['TestDate']]
#get the mean and count into new columns
df['MeanOp'] = df.groupby(['ClientID'])['Amount'].transform('mean')
df['NumberOp'] = df.groupby(['ClientID'])['Amount'].transform('count')
#drop duplicates and irrelevant columns
df = df.drop(['Amount','Date','LineNumber'],1).drop_duplicates()
```

output:

```
  ClientID    TestDate  MeanOp  NumberOp
1       1A  2019-12-24    22.5         2
4       1B  2019-08-26    70.0         1
```

**EDIT**: in case you want to preserve missing matching keys of `df2`:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['ClientID'], how='right')
df = df[(df['Date']<df['TestDate']) | (df['Date'].isnull())]
df['MeanOp'] = df.groupby(['ClientID'])['Amount'].transform('mean')
df['NumberOp'] = df.groupby(['ClientID'])['Amount'].transform('count')
df = df.drop(['Amount','Date','LineNumber'],1).drop_duplicates()
```

example:

```
df1:

  ClientID    TestDate
0       1A  2019-12-24
1       1B  2019-08-26
2       1C  2019-08-26

output:

  ClientID    TestDate  MeanOp  NumberOp
1       1A  2019-12-24    22.5         2
4       1B  2019-08-26    70.0         1
5       1C  2019-08-26     NaN         0
```

**UPDATE**: based on the edit on the post, if you want to group them by `(Client_ID, TestDate)`:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['ClientID'], how='right')
df = df[(df['Date']<df['TestDate']) | (df['Date'].isnull())]
df['MeanOp'] = df.groupby(['ClientID','TestDate'])['Amount'].transform('mean')
df['NumberOp'] = df.groupby(['ClientID','TestDate'])['Amount'].transform('count')
df = df.drop(['Amount','Date','LineNumber'],1).drop_duplicates()
```

output:

```
df1
  ClientID    TestDate
0       1A  2019-12-24
1       1B  2019-08-26
2       1B  2020-01-12
3       1C  2019-08-26

df2
   LineNumber ClientID        Date  Amount
0           1       1A  2020-01-12      50
1           2       1A  2019-09-24      15
2           3       1A  2019-12-25      20
3           4       1A  2018-12-30      30
4           5       1B  2018-12-30      60
5           6       1B  2019-12-12      40

df
  ClientID    TestDate  MeanOp  NumberOp
1       1A  2019-12-24    22.5         2
4       1B  2019-08-26    60.0         1
6       1B  2020-01-12    50.0         2
8       1C  2019-08-26     NaN         0
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works fine. But I'll still need your help. Sometimes, I have ClientID in my df1 that don't appear in my df2. For these clients, my old method created a line with `NumberOp = 0` and  `MeanOp = NaN`, while in your solution, this line is not created at all. Do you know how to have this same line ? In my problem, I don't want to "lose" a client, but I'd rather say that I have no operation info on him, so this difference is important for me.

Comment: @BeamsAdept You are welcome. Added the edit to the post to cover that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, it works in a general case.  I still have few problems, because in order to ask in SO, I simplified the problem a bit and now I'm stuck with this issue again : my df1 can in fact have multiple times the same client (so ClientID is not unique) but with different TestDate (corresponding to the date we take as reference to check operations). In these conditions, your method seems to have problems with the merge. That's totally my fault since I didn't precise it on my main problem, sorry for that.

Comment: @BeamsAdept nothing that cannot be fixed. It should work though. What seems to be the problem with Test_Date multiplicity of same Client_id? and how do you want the mean/count? is it per client_id or per (client_id, Test_Date)? please elaborate on real case so we can help better. Thank you.

Comment: I want my mean/count per (client_id, Test_Date) : My goal is to have, in df1, for each row, the mean and count of operations in df2, known as the date Test_Date (so done before Test_Date) for client Client_ID. Currently with your code, if a CLIENT_ID appears multiple time in df1, it will always have the same mean and count, no matter the Test_Date (I suppose with the merge, only one Test_Date is kept by Client_ID). I'll edit my main question in a way it shows the exact problem, illustrating with client 1B.

Comment: @BeamsAdept simply groupby (client_idm test_date). I will add the edit. Note that by your definition and new example, a date in df2 that is smaller than both Test_dates for the same client_id in df1, participates in both mean/count of corresponding Test_date. Is that what you wanted, or did you want to chunk the date intervals by Test_date?

Comment: @BeamsAdept Please checkout the update on the post to see if it resolves your issue. Thank you.

Comment: As you said, I want each date following my condition to participate in both mean and count, I didn't want to chunk the date intervals. Your fix seems to work perfectly, many thanks for all the time you took to help me !! I already tried to add the date in the groupby but I did it with Date and not TestDate, which obviously didn't work as I wanted, I feel stupid now -_-. Also sorry for late answer, I've had a few day break time.

Comment: I'm still having an issue with my first problem (the one you made an EDIT for). I edited my question ('Edit : Remaining issue :') to better explain what's wrong, because it seems in the 1st time that you gave me a fix for a different problem.